# No recocone el caracter | en una Expresión Regular, Typescript

Tags: typescript, regex

Tengo un arreglo de `string` que contiene cadenas con este formato

```
const regiser = "C0000002|ENG|P|L0000002|PF|S0007488|(+)-Cyanidanol|0|"
```

y para poder reconocer que es valida la cadena genere esta *Regex*:

```
const reg_1:RegExp = new RegExp('C[0-9]{7}\|[A-Z]{3}\|[A-Z]\|L[0-9]{7}\|[A-Z]{2}\|S[0-9]{7}\|.*?\|[0-9]\|')
```

Pero al utlizar el método `string.match(regrex)` solo reconoce hasta la primera barra `|` devolviendo `[ "C0000002" ]`, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que reconozca la cadena entera?, siendo que utilizo la barra invertida `\` para que `|` la reconozca como un caracter más y no como un caracter de opciones en las regex.

Comment: El problema es que lo estás pasando como un string al constructor `new RegExp()`. JavaScript *interpreta* el string `'ab\|cd'` como `ab|cd` y el regex lo recibe sin escapar, tomándolo como un `or`. Si lo pasás como string, hay que usar 2 barras: `\\|`... o mucho más sencillo, usar la sintaxis `/regex/` como ya te respondieron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Econtre que el código inicial funciona correctamente, pero para utilizar caracteres especiales de regex como caracteres ASCII se usa doble barra inversa `\\|`

```
const regiser = "C0000002|ENG|P|L0000002|PF|S0007488|(+)-Cyanidanol|0|";

function check_regexp(text:string):void {
    const regexp:RegExp = new RegExp('C[0-9]{7}\\|[A-Z]{3}\\|[A-Z]\\|L[0-9]{7}\\|[A-Z]{2}\\|S[0-9]{7}\\|.*?\\|[0-9]\\|','g');

    console.log(text.math(regexp));
}

check_regexp(register);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez el problema sea la manera en que ejecutas tu regex, a mí me funciona tu regex tal como está de la siguiente manera:

```js
const regex = /C[0-9]{7}\|[A-Z]{3}\|[A-Z]\|L[0-9]{7}\|[A-Z]{2}\|S[0-9]{7}\|.*?\|[0-9]\|/gm;
const str = `C0000002|ENG|P|L0000002|PF|S0007488|(+)-Cyanidanol|0|`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // Para evitar ciclos infinitos con cero matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // El resultado se accede con la variable m.
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Coincidencia hallada, grupo ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  });
}
```